# Extjs Custom component with button containing checkbox in the middle of it.

Tags: extjs

How can I create a custom component that has button containing a checkbox in the middle of it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create({
            xtype:'window',
            width:200,
            height:200,
            layout:'fit',
            title:'I\'m a test window',
            items:{
                xtype:'button',
                text:'<input type="checkbox" name="Check" value="Check" onclick=\'handleClick(this);\'/>',
                listeners:{
                    click: function(){
                        alert('buttonClick');
                    }
                }
            }
        }).show();
    }
});
function handleClick(checkbox){
    alert('checkbox click');
}
```

You can do what you want with this, the problem is to get checkbox events.

Comment: I would like add xtype button. Can I achieve it.

Comment: sure you can, but how you can check checkbox events?